# Full page screenshot with Cefsharp

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I have Cefsharp winforms v.104

I need to save a screenshot of the whole page. This code changes the browser's resolution. I think this is the wrong way.

Could you specify how to save the entire page correctly.

```
        int width = 1024;
        int height = 768;

        string jsString = "Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, " +
                          "document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, " +
                          "document.documentElement.offsetHeight, document.body.clientHeight, " +
                          "document.documentElement.clientHeight);";

        JavascriptResponse JSresponse = await chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsString);

        height = Convert.ToInt32(JSresponse.Result);

        var client = chromeBrowser.GetDevToolsClient();
        await client.Emulation.SetDeviceMetricsOverrideAsync(width, height, 1, true);

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        await chromeBrowser.CaptureScreenshotAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                byte[] b = t.Result;
                fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try the example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/104/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserForm.cs#L665

Answer (score 0):

thanks [amaitland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4583726/amaitland)

```
var contentSize = await chromiumWebBrowser.GetContentSizeAsync();

var viewPort = new DevTools.Page.Viewport
{
    Width = contentSize.Width,
    Height = contentSize.Height,
};

var data = await chromiumWebBrowser.CaptureScreenshotAsync(viewPort: viewPort, captureBeyondViewport: true);

var screenshotPath = @"D:\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".jpg";

File.WriteAllBytes(screenshotPath, data);
```